# AWS autoscaling group health check type : ELB or EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, autoscaling

I am creating an *internet-facing classic load balancer (CLB)*   with configurations as below

```
Connection Draining:Enabled, 300 seconds

health check configuration 
Ping Target 
TCP:22
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 2
Healthy threshold   10
```

and attach this CLB with an *auto scaling group (ASG)* with below configurations

```
Desired: 2
Availability Zone(s) : us-east-1a, us-east-1c
Min:2
Subnet(s) : subnet-0ab1df27,subnet-5dc8af06
Max: 20
Health Check Type: ELB
Health Check Grace Period: 300
Default Cooldown:300
```

---

below are the scaling policy attached with ASG

#### increase-instance-policy

> **Execute policy when:** aws-ec2-alarm-CPU-high-utilization
>    breaches the alarm threshold: CPUUtilization >= 70 for 2 consecutive periods of 300 seconds 
>    for the metric dimensionsAutoScalingGroupName = *demo-auto-scaling-group*
>   **Take the action:** Add 1 instances
>   **And then wait** 300 seconds before allowing another scaling activity

#### decrease-instance-policy

> **Execute policy when:** aws-ec2-alarm-CPU-low-utilization
>   breaches the alarm threshold: CPUUtilization <= 30 for 2 consecutive periods of 300 seconds the metric dimensions = *demo-auto-scaling-group*
>   **Take the action:** Remove  1 instances
>   **And then wait** 300seconds before allowing another scaling activity

BUT with above configurations instances are keep creating and terminating simultaneously without any CPU utilization?

Here is the activity history tab of ASG

> Description:DescriptionLaunching a new EC2 instance:
>   i-0768deac4d37591eb Cause:CauseAt 2017-01-03T10:11:42Z an instance was
>   started in response to a difference between desired and actual
>   capacity, increasing the capacity from 1 to 2.
>
> Description:DescriptionTerminating EC2 instance: i-0768deac4d37591eb
>   Cause:CauseAt 2017-01-03T10:19:02Z an instance was taken out of
>   service in response to a ELB system health check failure.

also on ELB page, instance tab list the instances but the status are always shown `OutOfService` with the info

> "Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health
>   checks consecutively."

---

But if I change **Health Check Type**: from **ELB to EC2** than everything works good; no multiple instances creations/termination

but [Here in this article](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/ec2-vs-elb-health-check-on-an-auto-scaling-group) I read that ELB health check is better than EC2 as it check EC instance health underneath;

--

kindly suggest me what wrong I am doing here; may be some time issue? as I am creating 2 instances and default cooldown time is 300 second and and meanwhile alarm is being is alarmed or any other issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you manually set the desired value?

Comment: no. all I did through AWS SDK

Comment: In your configuration I see you set the desired value to 2. It does not seem correct to me. Because the desired value is for forcing the ASG to change the number of instances regardless of the alarm. normally, it should not be set.

Comment: yes. I always want atleast 2 instance to running ; from AWS SDK "DesiredCapacity — (Integer)
The number of EC2 instances that should be running in the Auto Scaling group. This number must be greater than or equal to the minimum size of the group and less than or equal to the maximum size of the group."

Comment: but the termination happened because of ELB health check failure. isn't it?

Comment: If you need at least two instances you should set the `Min` value. The desired value is the current number of instances. The ASG adjusts this number based on the alarms.

Comment: If your alarm is working as expected, then just leave the desired value. Do not set it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132188/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-mahdi).

Comment: Double check the Security group between your instances and your ELB. If your ELB can not reach your instances over the ELB Health check port then it will never put them into service and continually terminate instances. [Here is the dev guide for ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html)

Comment: I am using the same security group for ELB and the instance. which enabled the inbound rule for 22 , icmp and some other tcp port.

Comment: you need two separate security groups, one for the ELB and one for Instances, In the instances security allow the health check port from the ELB security group.

Comment: I understand this is an old post, but the you find any reliable solution ? I am having a very similar problem for which the configuration seems to be adequate but my ELB keep terminating and instanciating server because of a health check failure although... @diEcho

Answer (score 3):

When using ELB health check, the Auto Scaling Group will rely on the ELB health check to determine if an instance is healthy or not. It looks like the ELB health check is failing, which causes the ASG to terminate the instance and launch a new one.

Are you sure the ELB health check is correctly configured? It looks you are checking port 22. The ELB will need to be able to access this port. Is your security group allowing this?

Comment: yes. The security group which is attached to ELB allows TCP 22.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the configuration of your load balancer. Change it as follows:

```
Timeout 30 seconds
Interval 60 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 10
Healthy threshold 2
```

Comment: let me check with these config

Comment: no affect . this still gives `OutOfService` in ELB instance status and sill it's terminating and creating the instances. btw does 60 seconds interval is not so high?